# What is the best practice to organize the main.tf with multiple application directories?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have 3 applications in separate directories handled with the kubernetes manifest files.

And I want to use terraform to deploy all the applications in different directories.

The structure of the applications show below.

```
app-1
  L kubernetes_manifest
    L deployment.yaml. ## use Dockerfile to run the app 
  L app
    L app.py
  Dockerfile. ## wrap the app
app-2
  L kubernetes_manifest
    L deployment.yaml. ## use Dockerfile to run the app 
  L app
    L app.py
  Dockerfile. ## wrap the app
app-3
  L kubernetes_manifest
    L deployment.yaml. ## use Dockerfile to run the app 
  L app
    L app.py
  Dockerfile. ## wrap the app
app_terraform
   L main.tf
```

main.tf

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "test_cluster" {
  project = "test"
  name     = "test-cluster"
  initial_node_count       = 1
}
```

Is there a way to deploy all the applications in `main.tf`?

Comment: How is the application source code and k8s manifests organized in git or other scm/vcs?

Comment: I would not have the cluster management and the apps in the same repo - they change in different pace and different intentions. Although, it is possible to have it.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I wrap the source code like `app.py` in a Dockerfile and use the dockerfile as a container in deployment.yaml to run. I use GIT under each app's root directory.

Answer (score 1):

I maintain the [Kustomization Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/kbst/kustomization/latest) which allows you to use native Kubernetes YAML in Terraform.

You can either use the provider directly or use a convenience module I additionally provide. I maintain both as part of my [Terraform framework for AKS, EKS and GKE](https://www.kubestack.com/).

The module approach may be more convenient, because then you can simply call the module once per app and have a good balance between maintainable code and no unnecessary coupling between the apps. The module also handles the [ids_prio approach](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/kbst/kustomization/latest/docs/resources/resource#terraform-limitation), which is more robust for larger numbers of K8s resources, out of the box.

## Option 1: Provider

`app-1.tf`:

```
data "kustomization_overlay" "app_1" {
  resources = [
    "${path.root}/app-1/kubernetes_manifest/deployment.yaml"
  ]
}

resource "kustomization_resource" "test" {
  for_each = data.kustomization_build.app_1.ids

  manifest = data.kustomization_build.app_1.manifests[each.value]
}
```

## Option 2: Module

`app-1.tf`:

```
module "app_1" {
  source  = "kbst.xyz/catalog/custom-manifests/kustomization"
  version = "0.1.0"

  configuration_base_key = "default"
  configuration = {
    default = {
      resources = [
        "${path.root}/app-1/kubernetes_manifest/deployment.yaml"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this is a good one for me to try.